# Using format to fill and justify multi-byte Unicode strings in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

In Python, it's easy to fill (i.e. pad) strings and justify them left, right, or center using `string.format`.  For example:

```
>>> word = "Resume"
>>> print "123456890\n{0:>{1}}".format(word, 10)
>>> print len(name)

1234567890
    Resume
6
```

However, if the string contains multi-byte Unicode characters, `string.format` doesn't calculate the string's width correctly:

```
>>> word = u"Résumé"
>>> print "123456890\n{0:>{1}}".format(word.encode('utf8'), 10)
>>> print len(name.encode('utf8'))

1234567890
  Résumé
8
```

The solution is *not* to use `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', string)`, as you may have read.  That will indeed [normalize Unicode character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) sequences (and it may also be necessary in some cases!) but it does *not* cause `string.format` to properly calculate the encoded width of strings for output to a terminal.

So how does one print correctly filled/padded strings with `string.format` in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as it turns out, is dead simple: Use Unicode literal format strings:

```
>>> word = u"Résumé"
>>> print u"123456890\n{0:>{1}}".format(word, 10)
>>> print len(name)

1234567890
    Résumé
6
```

This one-character solution seems to be hidden in a [message](https://bugs.python.org/issue7300#msg178617) from Victor Stinner on the Python bug tracker:

> Oh by the way, it's trivial to workaround this issue in Python 2: just use a Unicode format string. For example, replace `'{0}'.format(u'\u3042')` with `u'{0}'.format(u'\u3042')`.

I haven't found this in any StackOverflow answers, or on any pages found on Google, whether blogs, forums, mailing lists, etc.  So here it is!